# Integrate Uniform Server with PHP Storm?

Tags: php, mysql, uniform

I am using [Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/), and I created the MySQL connection with PHPStorm 
following this [similar tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE#InstallingandConfiguringXAMPPwithPhpStormIDE-IntegratingtheMySQLserver) (tailored to XAMPP)

When I run my simple PHP page containing:

```
mysql_connect("blabla",...)
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

What am I doing wrong?
Should I change any (restricted?) settings in MySQL?
I get the same error with every other MySQL functions.

When i test the MySQL connection in php storm it returns successful.

Comment: use PDO insted of mysql_*_old_deprecated_functions.

Comment: thanks but I still get the same error, with every other MySQL functions.

Comment: And what PhpStorm's own DB access components has to do with actual PHP code which is executed by **PHP itself**? It's your PHP issue -- it has NOTHING to do with PhpStorm.

Comment: php version is 5.5?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: 1) You need to make sure that `php_mysql.dll` extension is ENABLED in your php.ini. 2) Do not forget to restart Apache after making changes in php.ini.

Comment: php_mysql.dll extension is ENABLED

Comment: TRIPLE check that, because `mysql_connect` function is part of the `php_mysql` extension -- if it is disabled it will show exactly the same error (I just double checked this on my server). Maybe you have different extension enabled instead (e.g. `php_mysqli`)?

Comment: So the Q is: Where do you execute this script: CLI mode (console) or browser (web interface). The reason is -- it's possible that your setup (Uniform Server) has 2 separate php.ini -- one for CLI and one for web/Apache -- make sure that you are editing correct one (check `Loaded Configuration File` field from top table of the `phpinfo();` output).